# Django dynamic url

Tags: python, html, django

I trying to open content inside poster using a dynamic url, but I am facing a problem
my code is for a simple web page containing some movie posters and when I click on a poster new template on a new page should open which will show information about this poster.

**but whenever I click on a poster same template(index.html) opens in a new page instead of page.html**

eg

**127.0.0.1:8000/home** is web page with all posters and I clicked on poster1 with id=1 then in new page **127.0.0.1/home/1** will open but it is still index.html with all posters, not page.html in which content of poster1 id=1 is stored.

Here is my code

**homepage/models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Poster(models.Model):
    poster_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    poster_img = models.FileField(upload_to="poster_image/")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.poster_name


class Poster_page(models.Model):
    poster =  models.ForeignKey(Poster, default= 1)
    poster_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    poster_img = models.FileField()
    poster_details = models.TextField()
```

**homepage/views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from .models import Poster, Poster_page

def poster(request):
    pos = Poster.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('index.html', {'pos':pos})

def poster_page(request, id=1):
    poster_pg = Poster_page.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('page.html', {'poster_pg':poster_pg})
```

**homepage.url**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from.views import poster, poster_page


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^',poster),
    url(r'^home/(?P<id>/d+)/$', poster_page),
```

]

**poster.url**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^home/',include('homepage.urls', namespace='home'))
]


if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, 
    document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, 
    document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**index.html**

```
<body>
<div class="row">
    {% for poster in pos %}
    <div class="col-md-4">
        
            <a href="{{poster.id}}" target="new"><img src="{{ poster.poster_img.url }}" alt="image"><h3>{{ poster.poster_name }}</h3></a>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

**page.html**

```
<body>
<div class="row">
    <img src="{{ poster_img.url }}" alt="image"><h2>{{ poster_name }}</h2>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <h2>{{ poster_details }}</h2>       
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**homepage.url**

> Replace `d/+` by `\d+`

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views 

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$',views.poster),
    url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.poster_page),
]
```

Then **Try:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404

def poster_page(request, id):
    poster_pg = get_object_or_404(Poster_page, id=id)
    return render_to_response('page.html', {'poster_pg':poster_pg})
```

and **yes you also need** `<a href="/home/{{poster.id}}/">`.

Comment: not working, 127.0.0.1:8000/home/home/1 is opened in new tab

Comment: I had missed a `/` before home.

Comment: not working, 127.0.0.1:8000/home/1 is opened but it is not showing page.html it is again index.html

Comment: You had error in `homepage.urls` I have updated my answer, just check now.

Comment: 127.0.0.1:8000/home/1 opened but it does not match with any url pattern

Comment: url patterns are  1. ^admin/ 
2.^home/ ^$ 
3.^home/ ^(?P<id>/d+)/$ 
4.^static\/(?P<path>.*)$ 
5.^media\/(?P<path>.*)$

Comment: Now check once more, in `homepage.urls` instead `/d+` it should be `\d+`.

Answer (score 2):

In index.html you have not defined correct url in href to open poster detail.

Correct syntax would be like this:

```
<a href="home/{{poster.id}}" target="new"><img src="{{ poster.poster_img.url }}" alt="image"><h3>{{ poster.poster_name }}</h3></a>
```

Comment: it is not working, when i tried 127.0.0.1:8000/home/home/1 address is opened in new page

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in the view with the context variable -

```
return render_to_response('index.html', {'pos':pos})
```

should be -

```
return render_to_response('index.html', {'poster':pos})
```

Because in you are calling `{{poster.id}}` in index template.